# does this empty set code in Linq make a database call?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I came across this below line in an application I am working on. Wondering if its wrong to do this way:

```
var rows = from t in _modelRepository.Fetch<AssignTargetAutoGradeTABLENAME>() where false select t;
```

I am creating an empty set above. Does above line make a DB call to create the empty "rows"?

I would appreciate some insight.

Comment: @usr I doubt it. I mean, the fact that a LINQ2Entities query is a queryable and the fact that it's deferred doesn't destroy the point of just using a SQL profiler and execute the code yourself to check what's going on, instead of asking "Does this execute a SQL command?"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating this query object does not make a call but enumerating it does in both LINQ to SQL and Entity Framework. Obviously, this is LINQ provider specific.

SQL Server would optimize away the table access to a Constant Scan but the call still hits the database if the query is executed.

Comment: I believe that OP ignores what you've asked, but he/she's asking if executing the whole LINQ query would also send an actual command to the DB (i.e. when the queryable is enumerated...)

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer and I'm answering that in the first sentence(?).

Comment: I know, BTW I'm pretty sure that if the question was "why when I execute this LINQ query nothing hits the server" we would be voting to close as duplicate of *lot of* already published questions.........